# MakeTinyMCE v4 Tooltip Responsive

Tags: php, javascript, tinymce, visual-editor

Can anybody tell me that how to make the TinyMCE tooltip responsive? The tinymce editor is responsive but not the tooltip. Please help. I'm on tinymce 4.0.1 (latest)
please help

Comment: The tinymce tooltip like most tooltips uses absolute positioning. Resizing the screen to demonstrate the responsive design with a tooltip open will not work. I recommend closing the tooltip onresize.
If it's the size of the tool tip that's the problem you could try CSS queries for different screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks bro, but could you please give me some code example that how to do it?

Comment: Sure, can you send a link to your code and I'll have a look for you.

Comment: http://html-email.isaumya.com/ this is where I'm using the code, and I need to make the tooltip responsive...

Comment: Where is the tooltip?

Comment: tooltip means, all the popups, I mean whenever I click on insert image, video, source code etc, a popup comes, I wanna make that responsive.
Sorry for misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

As the tooltips are created dynamically you can remove them by targeting their class `mce-window` selector.
They will be recreated next time the window is requested.

Stick this in your javascript

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    $('.mce-window').remove();
});
```

Or if you prefer (both are identical):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.mce-window').remove();
});
```

Now whenever the page is resized, the tooltips will be removed.

Comment: Thank you for your effort brother, but it is not fixing my issue. I'm sharing my screenshot , I hope this will help you to easily understand my issue.

In the full screen: http://i.imgur.com/wByYTny.png [screenshot]

When screen goes smaller: http://i.imgur.com/yvXmHW1.png [screenshot]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've looked for the resize code but it's not there. Add the code above first and then I'll have another look. Also you have some errors: `$("#sendMail").validate()` is not a function and `$('#user').dropdownHover()` is not a function.

Comment: I have adder your code brother, now you please check and let me know what to do? I'm still having the issue for the mobile users.

Comment: OK I think I see the problem. Jquery should be loaded in the <head> tag. But you can just add the code after this line `$('#near-clouds').pan({fps: 30, speed: 1, dir: 'left', depth: 70});` It needs to be inside the document ready function

Comment: have done it, now at the time of resizing the screen the popup goes away but the black overlay still there. But in phone it's still same the popup does not auto re-sizing as per screen size.